# Tokenize integer value associated with 2 strings in same file

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program where it picks a random country and asks the user for the capital of the selected country. Whenever a country is picked the program also has to show if the surface area of it is either small, medium or big. I have to use an *enum* type for these, and the constants that must be used for each are: small(100K km), medium(400K km) and big(800K km). The file "countries.txt" contains a format that is read and tokenized (ex: New Zealand,Wellington,270534), but since I need to make a statement to check if the country's surface area is either small, medium or big, my guess is that the 3rd element needs to be passed as an *int*, so that I can create a statement to have the program assign a "size" and display it in a label depending on what the number is. I'm not sure how to declare the last part as an *int* though.

```
{
//  Declare enum
enum Surface
{
    Small, Medium, Big
}
//  Declare structure
struct Country
{
    //  Declare strings
    public string countryName;
    public string capital;
    public int size;
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //  Create List for CourseInfo
    private List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();



    Country currentCountry;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //  Declare integer variables for the counters and set to 0
    int correctCounter = 0;
    int incorrectCounter = 0;

    private void ReadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            //  Call StreamReader to use imported file
            StreamReader inputFile;
            string line;

            Country entry = new Country();

            //  Delimiter to separate values in text file
            char[] delim = { ',' };

            //  Open text file
            inputFile = File.OpenText("countries.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = inputFile.ReadLine();

                //  Tokenize the strings separated by the delimiter ','
                string[] tokens = line.Split(delim);

                entry.countryName = tokens[0];   //  Tokenized entry for COUNTRY
                entry.capital = tokens[1];       //  Tokenized entry for CAPITAL

                countryList.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  Shows error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    //  Method displays selected size
    private void DisplaySize(Surface size)
    {
        //  Assign to label
        sizeAnswerLabel.Text = size.ToString();
    }
    private void DisplayCountry()
    {
        //  Create random variable
        Random rand = new Random();

        //  Country us randomly chosen from the list
        int countryPosition = rand.Next(countryList.Count);

        //  Selected country
        currentCountry = countryList[countryPosition];

        //  Show selected country in Label
        countryAnswerLabel.Text = currentCountry.countryName;
    }

    private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Closes the form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Call method to load StreamReader with the file
        ReadFile();
    }

    private void QuizButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Call method to show random country
        DisplayCountry();
    }

    private void CheckAnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  If the input is correct, +1 for the correct counter
        if (currentCountry.capital == capitalAnswerTextBox.Text)
        {
            correctCounter++;
            correctLabel.Text = correctCounter.ToString();
        }
        //  If the input is incorrect, +1 for the incorrect counter
        else
        {
            incorrectCounter++;
            incorrectLabel.Text = incorrectCounter.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void NextQuestionButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Clears input TextBox
        capitalAnswerTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
        DisplayCountry();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you need this declaration `Country entry = new Country();` outside the `while` loop? Well, the `Country` is a `struct`, you don't modify the same instance, but it looks strange. Have you tried just to parse a size `entry.size = int.Parse(tokens[2]);`?

Comment: I made it a global variable to use in my rand statement. I had trouble trying to find out how to parse the int correctly but that seemed to work